# Is it possible to resize with the arrow cursors like browsers' resizing actions on vuetify datatable?

Tags: datatable, resize, vuetify.js

I would like to resize the table which I made with the vuetify datatable in a page with the arrow cursors just like any browsers could be resized.

I found the arrow cursor setting with css

```
cursor: ns-resize;
```

but, don't have any ideas of the action.

Very thankful to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from css.

[resize from MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

```
table tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  resize: vertical;  // options: both, horizontal, etc.
}
```

Comment: however, it doesn't work perfectly. It looks like textfield. If you stretched once it doesn't change rows of data.